# How can I pass structs from an Actix middleware to the handler?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm trying to write an authentication middleware for my Actix application. When validating the request in the middleware, I make a call to a database to retrieve the necessary user data to validate the incoming request. Once the request has been authorised, I want to be able to pass this user data to the handler as this will allow me to avoid having the query for the same data twice.

I can't find a solution for this. The best suggestion I could find so far was to ["set a request extension"](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/855). There doesn't seem to be any examples for this and there is also too little documentation around this to work out what to do here.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/63158225/1418750 Or even more comple https://web.archive.org/web/20200811175006if_/https://github.com/Luis-Hebendanz/tagify-backend/blob/master/src/my_identity_service.rs#L217

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make protected routes in actix-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62269278/how-can-i-make-protected-routes-in-actix-web)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass data from middleware (service) to handler via extensions.

First of all you have to insert extension (in service).
The `HttpMessage` trait is implemented for `ServiceRequest` struct  and provides `extensions_mut()` function. It must be mutable because you will be inserting new extension.

It might look something like this:

```rust
req.extensions_mut().insert(user);
```

Then you have to implement `FromRequest` trait for your data structure.

```rust
impl FromRequest for User {
    type Error = actix_web::Error;
    type Future = futures::future::Ready<Result<Self, Self::Error>>;
    type Config = ();

    fn from_request(req: &HttpRequest, payload: &mut Payload) -> Self::Future {
        match req.extensions().get::<User>() {
            Some(user) => return ok(user.clone()),
            None => return err(actix_web::error::ErrorBadRequest("ups..."))
        };
    }

}
```

Then you're ready to use it in handler.

```rust
pub async fn get_user_handler(user: User) {}
```

Comment: really nice answer, thanks! It is worth to mention that `User` must have derived `Clone`

Comment: As of actix-web 3.2.0, there is the [`ReqData`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/actix_web/web/struct.ReqData.html) extractor. So you can use a `ReqData<User>` parameter in your handler instead of implementing `FromRequest` for `User`.

Comment: Note that the ok and err types come from the "futures" crate on crates.io. Not shown in the example is `use futures::future::{ok, err};`