# How passing ScyllaDB connection in Rust Actix

Tags: rust, actix-web, scylla

I have problems implement scylla-rust-driver on Rust Actix. I want just create simple CRUD with scyllaDb.

First i create struct for App Data

```rust
    struct AppState {
      scy_session: Session,
      app_name: String,
    }
```

Next i create Simple function

```rust
    #[get("/")] 
    async fn index(data: web::Data<AppState>) -> String {
       // I want to CRUD in this function with ScyllaDB
       let app_name = &data.app_name; // <- get app_name
       format!("Hello {}!", app_name) // <- response with app_name
    }
```

And finally main.rs is

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let session: Session = SessionBuilder::new()
        .known_node("localhost:9042")
        .user("username", "password")
        .build()
        .await
        .expect("Some error message");

    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .data(AppState {
                scy_session: session,
                app_name: String::from("Actix-web"),
            })
            .service(index)
    })
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

But show error :

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Session: Clone` is not satisfied in `[closure@src/main.rs:27:21: 34:6]`
  --> src/main.rs:27:5
   |
27 |       HttpServer::new(|| {
   |  _____^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^_-
   | |     |
   | |     within `[closure@src/main.rs:27:21: 34:6]`, the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `Session`
```

How actually implement scylla-rust-db on Actix web ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Not tested at all, but what if you add the `move` keyword to the closure? `HttpServer::new(move || {`

Comment: still same error Mr. @yolenoyer - Thanks anyway

```
  #[actix_web::main]
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ within `[closure@src/main.rs:27:21: 34:10]`, the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `Session`
...
27 |       HttpServer::new(move||{
   |  _____________________-
28 | |         App::new()
29 | |             .data(AppState {
30 | |                 scy_session: session,

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special with Session, as seen here https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-rust-driver/blob/main/examples/parallel-prepared.rs

The solution is to wrap it in an `Arc`. We don't necessary need to do so ourselves as `web::Data` does this itself.  Here is what I got.

```
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};

use scylla::{Session, SessionBuilder};

struct AppState {
    scy_session: Session,
    app_name: String,
}

/// Use the `Data<T>` extractor to access data in a handler.
async fn index(data: web::Data<AppState>) -> impl Responder {
    let app_name = &data.app_name; // <- get app_name
    HttpResponse::Ok().body(format!("Hello {}!", app_name))
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let session: Session = SessionBuilder::new()
        .known_node("localhost:9042")
        .user("username", "passwor")
        .build()
        .await
        .expect("Some error message");
    let data = web::Data::new(AppState {
        scy_session: session,
        app_name: String::from("Actix-web"),
    });

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .data(data.clone())
            .route("/", web::get().to(index))
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67772754/1418750

Comment: Wow - Its works.
But now show error : 
thread 'main' panicked at 'there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime', /Users/hhh/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.13.0/src/runtime/context.rs:37:26
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Panic in Arbiter thread.

Comment: Possibly because of actix versions, you didnt state which you are using.

Comment: I am use this
actix-web="3"
actix-rt="1.1.1"
scylla = "0.2.1"
tokio="0.2.25"

Comment: Yes correct, after i change version all work well
actix-web = "4.0.0-beta.5"
tokio = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["time"] }
Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm curious why `Session` does not need to be wrapped in a `Mutex`. Seems to be working fine without it.

Comment: @nomad Why would session need a mutex?

Comment: @PamungkasJayuda In case it gets shared between different threads spawned by actix. No?

Comment: Yes hence the `Arc/Data` wrapper. We don't expect to mutate the session though.