# How do I access the app_data in actix_web's Guard::check() function?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am trying to implement a custom guard that checks if the authorization token is valid:

```
impl Guard for AuthGuard {
    fn check(&self, ctx: &GuardContext<'_>) -> bool {
        // check header value here
        // and retrieve connection pool from app_data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at [GuardContext](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/guard/struct.GuardContext.html), you can see that there is `req_data` and `head`. And hence one can do.

```
impl Guard for AuthGuard {
    fn check(&self, ctx: &GuardContext<'_>) -> bool {
        let jwt = ctx.req_data::<Jwt>().unwrap();
        let token = ctx.head().headers().get(header::AUTHORIZATION).unwrap();
        jwt.is_valid(token)
    }
}
```

The things you are asking for are there but remember that Checks are blocking.

- Checks can be good to check whether a token exists and its valid.
- Checks are not suitable in a scenario where you need to check if a token exists in Redis or sqlx pool.

If you need to do async stuff you might need to think of `FromRequest` or middleware. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62269278/how-can-i-make-protected-routes-in-actix-web).